# Trying to verify last position of a string

Tags: python

Im trying to verify if the last char is not on my list

```
def acabar_char(input):
    list_chars = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".split()
    tam = 0
    tam = (len(input)-1)
    for char in input:
        if char[tam] in list_chars:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

When i try this i get this error:

```
if char[tam] in list_chars:
```

> IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: `if chars in list_chars`

Comment: `for char in input:` means char is taking 1 character/string at a time, assuming input is a string. `char[tam]` then, as the code rightly complains, would be out of range, because `tam = (len(input)-1)`.

Comment: Also note: Your loop `for char in input:` will only run once because you use `return`; it never gets to the second iteration

Comment: @PedroGabriel I suggest using the constants `string.ascii_letters` and `string.digits` from the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) to make the code more readable and reduce opportunities for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to assert that the last element of an input string (or also list/tuple) is NOT in a subset of disallowed chars.

Currently, your loop never even gets to the second and more iteration because you use `return` inside the loop; so the last element of the input only gets checked if the input has length of 1.

I suggest something like this instead (also using the [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) definition):

```
import string
DISALLOWED_CHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def acabar_char(val, disallowed_chars=DISALLOWED_CHARS):
    if len(val) == 0:
        return False

    return val[-1] not in disallowed_chars
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 2):

you can index from the end (of a sting or a list) with negative numbers

```
def acabar_char(input, list_cars):
    return input[-1] is not in list_chars
```

Answer (score 0):

you are already iterating through your list in that for loop, so theres no need to use indices. you can use list comprehension as the other answer suggest, but I'm guessing you're trying to learn python, so here would be the way to rewrite your function.

```
list_chars = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".split()
for char in input:
    if char in list_chars:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: the title says "Trying to verify LAST position of a string"

Answer (score -1):

```
list_chars = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".split()    
def acabar_char(input):
    if input in list_chars:
        print('True')
```